# How to prevent generated Java Protobuf files to be created in the build directory?

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, protoc

Currently I have my build.gradle being specified to generate the Java Protobuf files to a specific directory :

```
sourceSets {
main {
    proto {
        srcDir("src/main/java/proto")
    }
}

protobuf {
  protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protocVersion" }
    plugins {
      grpc {
        artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:$grpcVersion"
     }
   }
  generateProtoTasks {
    ofSourceSet("main").forEach {
        it.plugins {
            grpc
        }
     }
  }

  generatedFilesBaseDir = "src/main/java/proto"
}
```

However it continues to be generated in my gradle build directory, which is then causing issues because the generated Java Protobuf files sees the files in the build directory and views it as a duplicates. Is there any way to prevent it from being generated in the build directory and only having the Java Protobuf files generated in the directory I specify it to generate to?

Comment: Could you add a `Delete` task to run after the generate task to clean up the build folder...?  `tasks.generateProtos.finalizedBy tasks.cleanUpBuildProtos` ?

Answer (score 0):

generatedFilesBaseDir just causes a copy to be made, so this is working as intended.  Gradle needs the generated files to be in the build directory to identify whether or not to rebuild them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).